# Powerbi create mesaure from multiple tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a measure where i get the ammount of written hours in a shift. The issue is that my DAX knowledge is not sufficient to create such a formula.

The tables are as follows:

```
TABLE 1 (Shift information)

END      |  START   | EMPLOYEE
datetime | datetime | varchar

TABLE 2 (Written time)

END      |  START   | DURATION | EMPLOYEE
datetime | datetime | duration | varchar
```

Now i have created an simular SQL to create this data, unfortunately the SQL is so intensive that it would take too long to run it.

The formula in the SQL is as follows:

```
SUM(table2.duration) WHERE table2.end BETWEEN table1.start and table1.end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are the tables related? On employee ID?

Comment: They are related on employee ID yes

Answer (score 0):

Try DATESBETWEEN

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( table2[duration] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        table2[end],
        LASTDATE ( table1[start] ),
        LASTDATE ( table1[end] )
    )
)
```